# How to determine if a process has GUI or not?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

How to determine if a process has responsive GUI or rather it's a background application? May be there are some API function calls that are necessarily made?

(The answer doesn't necessarily has to involve API calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest Windows API call to deduce this information would be [GetGUIThreadInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506.aspx). Note the following paragraph from the *Remarks* section:

> If the specified thread **does not** exist or **have an input queue**, the function will fail.

A thread with an input queue can potentially own windows. Note that a thread with an input queue is not required to create windows. Note also, that a non-GUI-thread can be propagated to a GUI-thread at any point.

---

*Note: Even though executable images specify the [subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cc7ya5b.aspx), under which they run (e.g. `CONSOLE` or `WINDOWS`), this cannot be used to distinguish between a process with a GUI and a 'background process'. A process running in the `CONSOLE` subsystem can create a GUI just as well.*

Comment: regarding the note: yes, i considered subsystem type to be the source until i realized that it can't be reliable.

Comment: also, i differentiate background processes and console processes. console process is not a background process.

Comment: @Nika: That's an odd distinction. Or rather, what then is a 'background process'? A `CONSOLE` process can be created using [CREATE_NO_WINDOW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx), and suddenly become indistinguishable from a 'background process'.

Comment: yes. my concern is, is it present on the taskbar? is it visible to the user?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze: You could enumerate visible windows using `EnumWindows()` and see if any belong to the target process using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`. A window is on the taskbar if it is a top-level window and has the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style.